# Sharepoint GetUserProfilePropertyFor not returning any results

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to get the SharePoint 2013 API for GetUserProfileProperty, when I put the below url into a browser it works finr, however when i run the below code, I get no result (I do get a return, but the property is blank - 
LOG: D1: {"d":{"GetUserProfilePropertyFor":""}} ) (stringify was only used to see the results without needing debug

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://sp.net/sites/xmas/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='MAIN\R5454D'",
type: "GET",
headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function (d1) {
    var res = JSON.stringify(d1)
    if (console) { console.log('D1: ' + res); };
},
});
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslash properly in he username

Comment: Perfect, thanks Robert - just that simple, replaced \ with %5C (I had tried encoding the whole URL but not just the backslash!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the script below to check the users department and set a link on the startpage directly to his/her department-teamsite. I did this in my custom masterpage.

Don't forget to add a link to e.g. "jquery-1.8.3.min.js" in your head tag.

Maybe it helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
var loginName = "";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

function GetCurrentUser() {

var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccessA,
  error : onErrorA
});
}

function onSuccessA(data, request){

    // alert("Success One");
    // cutting of i:0#.w|
    var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];

    var repOne = "%5C";  
    var repTwo = "%2E";
    // alert("before replace: " + loginName);

    loginName = loginName.replace(/\\/g, repOne); // replace \ with %5C
    loginName = loginName.replace(/\./g, repTwo); // replace . with %2E

    // alert("after replace: " + loginName);

    GetCurrentUserDepartment(loginName); // call next function to get department. Pass the loginname into the function
}

function onErrorA(error) {

  alert(error);
}

GetCurrentUser();

});

function GetCurrentUserDepartment(loginNameAcc) {
// alert("LoginName: " + loginNameAcc)
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Department')?@v=" + "'" + loginNameAcc + "'";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  method: "GET",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccessB,
  error : onErrorB
});
}

function onSuccessB(data){

    var department = data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;
    // alert("Team:" + department);
    var departmentArray = new Array(    
        "Information Technology",
        "Human Resources");

    var departmentArrayURL = new Array(     
        "information-technology-workspace",
        "human-resources-workspace");

    // set link to logged in users department
    switch(department){
        default:
            // alert("case default");
            break;
        case departmentArray[0]:
            // alert("case IT Team");
            document.getElementById("teamoverview").innerHTML = "<a href='/teams/"+departmentArrayURL[0]+"'>Workspace</a>";
            break;
        case departmentArray[1]:
            // alert("case HR Team");
            document.getElementById("teamoverview").innerHTML = "<a href='/teams/"+departmentArrayURL[1]+"'>Workspace</a>";
            break;
        }    
}

function onErrorB(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
        alert("Error: " + jqxr.responseText)
}

</script>
```

I'm a starter in writing scripts like that. So please forgive my script skills.

If you like it, give it a vote up, or mark it as the answer if it fits for you.